# Lerp vs. Animation

Tags: unity, animation, lerp

I've read a few posts regarding lerp and animation, but none seemingly fully answer my question - or I'm not reading into them correctly.

Lets say I have a box in a game. This box has a lid, and the only way it opens is via user interaction (eg. put aside physics if it were to hang upside down; a user presses 'E' and the box opens).

Now, I can achieve this one of two ways.

1) I animate the model of the box with an "Open" animation - the box lid rotating on it's X axis until the model constitutes an 'open' box; OR

2) I lerp the box lid from closed to open over time using rotation on it's X axis until again, the model constitutes an 'open' box.

Apart from the post [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/709474/animation-vs-lerp-movetowards-performance-comparis.html) showing that:

> ...through script, MoveTowards method caused up to 0.10 ms latency while
>   playing regular animation almost made no change. If there was anything
>   it could be something between 0.1 and 0.3 ms.

Is there any reason why one would be preferred over the other? I personally would prefer to use Lerp as that way, I can make a generic 'Open' class that I can attach to the box lid, and then to a door, just changing the axis on which it pivots.

Any ideas, thoughts or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Lerp` solution works well for this one animation for this one box.

But what if your graphics department gets the idea to replace the box [with one which has a more fancy opening animation with far more moving parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVJ-ZpdGXx4)?

Doing that as an animation in the 3d modeling program might be far easier than animating all the sub-models with scripts. It also allows to simply replace the 3d model with a differently animated one in a simple drag-and-drop manner without having to change any code.

But when you don't plan to have such complex animations in your game, then using the animation system might be overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That explains in which circumstances animation is better than programmatically attaining the desired result, and vice versa. As I am going for simplicity for a proof of concept, I will stick with `Lerp`, but further down the track I will look to do some work with animations. Thank you again!

Comment: Note that usually underneath the animation frameworks there is `Lerp`ing going on. animations are often based on keyframe, with lerp (or easing curves) to move from frame to frame. A complex animation system can have keyframes for each component instead of keyframes for the entire thing. See for example the [Dope sheet in Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-dopesheet) where each component has it's own timeline and keyframes. For your relative simple animation, a `Lerp` might be sufficient though. Just pointing out that animation system is a more complex implementation of the lerp method.

Comment: @Felsir, thanks for going into that level of depth and thanks for the link; it is an interesting read! I am looking at doing animations for the more complex movements; skeletal, multi-joint, complex movement animations, etc. but like to explore each avenue to see what works and how it works - so your explanation is perfect, it helps me understand how it works. Thank you!